# readAnyDatabase user can create a database on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

the following code leaves an empty *dummy* database. Is this system behavior intended?
mongodb is running --auth mode and the user is part of the readAnyDatabase Role.

`import pymongo
    print CORE_PROD_URL
    mongo = pymongo.MongoClient(CORE_PROD_URL)
    print mongo.database_names()
    print mongo.dummy.test.count()
    print mongo.database_names()`

which gives:

`mongodb://read_only_user:pw@localhost:27017
    [u'admin', u'local']
    0
    [u'admin', u'local',  u'dummy']`

the same behaviour happens with find()

while

```
mongo.dummy.test.insert({‘foo’: ‘bar’})
```

throws an exception

```
OperationFailure: not authorized on new_db to execute command
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, [SERVER-11051](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11051). The database name will disappear from "database_names()" the next time you restart the server, but of course it will reappear next time you read from the "dummy" database.